# How do I build and install applications on a jailbroken iPhone without being in the iPhone Developer Program?

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, jailbreak

I would like to build and install my app on my jailbroken device without paying the $99 required for the iPhone Developer Program.  I have Rock and Cydia... what is the easiest way to do it (if it's possible)?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

That's a broad question.

I recommend [iPhone Open Application Development](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780596155346), 2nd Edition By: Jonathan Zdziarski.

The Open Development tools require the Apple Tools. You can download the Apple Development tools for free from the Apple Developer site. The $99 fee is just if you want to install and deploy in a fashion compatible with the App store.

Comment: I would like to test my app on my iPhone before I pay the $99 just to see if my project is able to work on the iPhone and not waste my money... but I get the error: Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

Comment: You might should have made that your question. I'm not a jailbreak expert but it sounds like the phone isn't actually broke out. When you jailbreak a phone it stops looking for the certs. You should try the jailbreak again. Make sure you have the latest versions because Apple keeps plugging the holes used to break out the phones.

Comment: TechZen, the error "Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain" is from XCode, not the phone.