# Using the 4.2 SDK, how do I install on a jailbroken device without paying?

Tags: iphone, ipad, jailbreak

I'm having trouble installing my application on a jailbroken device without being a paid member of the iPhone Developer Program. It seems like I've tried everything.  I've tried:

- Building the .app , placing it in a Payload folder, zipping it and
  changing to .ipa.
- Building to an .app and manually playing that in the /Applications
  folder and respringing

I'm using the 4.2 SDK and attempting to test on a jailbroken 4.2.1 iPad.  Whenever I get the app on there and try and launch it, it crashes immediately.  It works flawlessly on the simulator.

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708444/how-do-i-build-and-install-applications-on-a-jailbroken-iphone-without-being-in-t/2708964#2708964)

Comment: Try doing it to "right" way. You'll be surprised at how it works.

Comment: Thanks, but that solution (and even an updated form of that solution) and had no luck. It appears that information regarding this topic becomes outdated very quickly.

Comment: The jailbroke/open tool chain is updated by volunteers so it lags considerably behind the system revs. Expect continuous problems of this kind.

Answer (score 2):

If you pay the $99 to enroll and get an iOS Developers certificate, you'll be able to deploy the app to the device with the Xcode debugger, and likely see exactly why the app is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to find a friend with an account already and have them set you up.  Not sure how that jives with any terms in the agreement.