# Custom Xcode app into jailbroken iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, jailbreak

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I build and install applications on a jailbroken iPhone without being in the iPhone Developer Program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708444/how-do-i-build-and-install-applications-on-a-jailbroken-iphone-without-being-in-t)

I am a beginner IOS developer and i have a question to make. I want to test the apps I develop in my device but Xcode says "unknown IOS found". My iPhone is jailbroken. Is there any way to make this happen? Via iFile maybe?

Comment: Did you pay the 99 USD for the program?

Comment: I do not have a developer licence but Xcode was bought from iTunes