# ios xcode 4.5 over wifi

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak

I'm new to iOS developement and I 'm doing ok so far, however I am still trying to find a way to send an application to the device via wifi. My device is jailbroken and iTunes can sync over wifi, but there's no way I can make xcode to see it.

Any chance that I can upload and perhaps debug over wifi? I don't want to send the application with ssh manually.

Comment: Do you have a developer account with ios program purchsed?

Comment: This functionality appeared in an earlier version of Xcode, but was highly unstable and has since been removed.

Comment: Yes I have a dev account. So there's no choice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the Xcode 4.2 preference "Support Wirelessly Connected Devices" do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266391/what-does-the-xcode-4-2-preference-support-wirelessly-connected-devices-do)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you a bit. Look at this similar post:

[How do I build and install applications on a jailbroken iPhone without being in the iPhone Developer Program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708444/how-do-i-build-and-install-applications-on-a-jailbroken-iphone-without-being-in)

But I think running and debugging is not possible in xcode over wifi!

Comment: No, this is about installing when you are not in the iOS program. I 'm already in.