# Running an iOS app to a non registered device

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to the field, so excuse my ignorance.

I have a registered iOS device (iPhone 4) and I am developing my application with the Xcode IDE. I recently purchased a new device (iPhone 5) and I want to run the app there as well.

I know the standard procedure, i.e. provisioning profiles, UUID etc, however I would like to know if there is a "hack" in order to run the app to the unregistered device via Xcode.

The application is already in the AppStore, however I would like to test a development version to multiple devices, before updating my patch.

Comment: nop, you have to follow the standard procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can't do that  without adding udid in provisining profile, that is not possible for sure

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately,as i know you can't. 
 [According to Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-CODE_SIGNING_IN_A_NUTSHELL-IPHONE_CERTIFICATES)

or without [jailbreaking your iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708444/how-do-i-build-and-install-applications-on-a-jailbroken-iphone-without-being-in) you can not install your app on it.

Hope this [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)  will helps you